# Is there a jOOQ tool to verify generated definitions are still correct?

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I am working with classes generated by jOOQ based on a schema maintained by Liquibase.  I am looking for a way to ensure that the jOOQ classes remain consistent with the actual database. The preferred approach is to create a test that can be run by our CI tool when pull requests are created.

Is there a tool to verify that the jOOQ generated definitions are still correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two obvious approaches involving your build setup are:

- To check in generated sources (get a diff when they're not up to date). See also the manual section about [code generation and version control](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-version-control/).
- To include both Liquibase migrations and jOOQ code generation in your build. That way, the generated sources *and* the database are *always* up to date with what is defined in your Liquibase migration scripts. You can also base your code generation directly on your Liquibase files using the [`LiquibaseDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/), if you're not doing anything fancy, vendor specific.

A less obvious way using programmatic jOOQ API is to compare two versions of `Meta` using [`Meta.migrateTo(Meta)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html#migrateTo(org.jooq.Meta)):

```java
// This corresponds to the meta data from your live connection
Meta m1 = ctx.meta();

// This corresponds to the meta data from your generated catalog (or schema, table, etc)
Meta m2 = ctx.meta(catalog);

// This is a generated migration script between the two versions, should be empty
Queries queries = m1.migrateTo(m2);
```

The approach might work, though it has a lot of caveats, which are still being fixed as of jOOQ 3.14, 3.15. Work in progress can be seen here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/projects/1, bug reports very welcome!